# How to set an html element's height as { 100% - 10em from bottom }

Tags: html, css

Let's consider one element `#top`. I want it's height to be 100% of the page, but diminished by 10em from the bottom. I'm unable to figure out how to do it. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}
#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEqYMK (for illustration, i have shown one more element, `#bottom`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo is lil weird but anyways, if you want to deduct `10em` from `100%` then use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) property like

```
#top {
    width: 100%; /* You won't need this */
    height: calc(100% - 10em);
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hoh0m85s/)

Note : I've removed `position: absolute;`, `margin-left` like properties from your demo because I have no idea why you were using them at first place but if you want you can still use them.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! calc() seems to have excellent browser support too. Long story about `position:absolute`, but irrelevant here clearly. I can (and will) accept your answer after 4 more min apparently.

Comment: @KayaToast No issues, glad to help you out :)